# Multiselect/Multicategory Checkbox Filtering with Knockoutjs

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I'm relatively new to Knockoutjs and trying implement some advanced filtering. I'm looking to filter my viewmodel data using multiple categories using a series of checkboxes.

I've followed a number of solutions which allow filtering based on one criteria/category at a time. However, I've been unable to get the advanced filtering working. Problem occurs when i'm filtering based on values in the nested array. e.g. education.course. Appears to work fine where the selected course corresponds to an object which has only one course within its education array. But when de/selecting a course that matches an object with multiple courses within its education array, the vm "breaks"/stops working and console logs "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'course' of undefined". Haven't been able to resolve that error.

I've set-up some sample data/and my current version of the view model in this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ozi01/wwT3Y/)**.
Also see below the current viewmodel.

Would appreciate any assistance on this.

Thanks.

```
function vm(data) {
var vm = this;
vm.people = ko.observableArray();
ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, vm.people);
vm.selectedCourses = ko.observableArray();
vm.selectedSchools = ko.observableArray();
vm.selectedLocations = ko.observableArray();

vm.filtered = ko.computed(function () {
    var result;
    var self = this;
    result = $.grep(self.people(), function (person, i) {
        var remove = false;
        if (self.selectedLocations().length > 0) {
            if (person {
                remove = remove || self.selectedLocations().indexOf(person.statename()) === -1
            } else {
                remove = true
            }
            }

            if (self.selectedCourses().length > 0 || self.selectedSchools().length>0) {
                if (person) {
                    var edResult;
                    var m1, mCourse, mSchool;
                    var position = 0;
                    var mCoursep = [];
                    var mSchoolp = [];

                    edResult = $.grep(person.education(), function (education, i) {
                        if (education) {
                            mCourse = self.selectedCourses().indexOf(education.course());
                            mSchool = self.selectedSchools().indexOf(education.name());
                            if (mCourse > -1) {
                                m1 = true;
                                mCoursep[position] = i;

                            }
                            if (mSchool > -1) {
                                m1 = true;
                                mSchoolp[position]=i;
                            }
                            position++;
                        }
                        return m1 === true
                    });

                    if (edResult.length > 0) {
                        for (i = 0; i < mCoursep.length; i++) {
                            remove = remove || self.selectedCourses().indexOf(person.education()[mCoursep[i]].course()) === -1;
                        }
                        for(i=0;i<mSchoolp.length;i++){ remove=remove||self.selectedSchools().indexOf(person.education()[mSchoolp[i]].name())===-1;
                    }

                    } else {
                        remove = true
                    }
                }

            }
            return !remove
        });
    return result
    }, vm);
};



vm.uniqueFilters = ko.computed(function () {
    var uniqueCourses = ["Arabic Studies", "Chinese", "English and International Studies", "European and Nigerian Languages", "French", "History and Diplomacy Studies", "International Relations and Strategic Studies", "Kiswahili", "Language and Linguistics", "Languages Arts & Yoruba", "Management Technology", "Medical Laboratory and Technology", "Modern European Languages", "Russian with French/German"];
    var uniqueSchools = ["ABTI", "Abia State University Uturu", "Abubakar Tafawa Balewa University Bauchi", "Achievers University Owo Ondo State", "Ambrose Alli University Ekpoma", "Babcock University Ilishan-Remo", "Bells University of Technology Ota", "Bingham University New Karu", "Delta State University Abraka", "Federal University of Technology Akure", "Modibbo Adama University of Technology Yola", "Rivers State University of Science and Technology Port Harcourt"];
    var uniqueLocations = ["Abia", "Bauchi", "Cross River", "Delta", "Lagos", "Plateau", "Rivers"]

    return {
        uniqueCourses: uniqueCourses.sort(),
        uniqueSchools: uniqueSchools.sort(),
        uniqueLocations: uniqueLocations.sort()
    };
});

var sampleData = [{
    "firstname": "Ngozi",
        "lastname": "Osadebe",
        "statename": "Abia",
        "ratename": "Declined",
        "education": [{
        "course": "French",
            "name": "Delta State University Abraka",
            "awards": "BSc.",
            "gpa": "3.2"
    }, {
        "course": "History and Diplomacy Studies",
            "name": "Ambrose Alli University Ekpoma",
            "awards": "MSc.",
            "gpa": "3.1",
            "statename": "Abia"
    }]
}, {
    "firstname": "Chinedu",
        "lastname": "Okorie",
        "statename": "Lagos",
        "ratename": "Not Rated",
        "education": [{
        "course": "European and Nigerian Languages",
            "name": "Modibbo Adama University of Technology Yola",
            "awards": "MSc.",
            "gpa": "3.2"
    }, {
        "course": "Kiswahili",
            "name": "Ambrose Alli University Ekpoma",
            "awards": "BSc.",
            "gpa": "4.6"
    }]
}, {
    "firstname": "Joachim",
        "lastname": "Okeke",
        "statename": "Lagos",
        "ratename": "Not Rated",
        "education": [{
        "course": "Languages Arts & Yoruba",
            "name": "Federal University of Technology Akure",
            "awards": "BSc.",
            "gpa": "2.8"
    }]
}, {
    "firstname": "Chantelle",
        "lastname": "Tom",
        "statename": "Plateau",
        "ratename": "Not Rated",
        "education": [{
        "course": "Russian with French\/German",
            "name": "Bingham University New Karu",
            "awards": "MSc.",
            "gpa": "3.4"
    }, {
        "course": "International Relations and Strategic Studies",
            "name": "Bells University of Technology Ota",
            "awards": "BSc.",
            "gpa": "4.4"
    }]
}, {
    "firstname": "Simisola",
        "lastname": "Lawson",
        "statename": "Abia",
        "ratename": "Not Rated",
        "education": [{
        "course": "Language and Linguistics",
            "name": "Abia State University Uturu",
            "awards": "BSc.",
            "gpa": "3.1"
    }]
}, {
    "firstname": "Chuba",
        "lastname": "Okadigbo",
        "statename": "Bauchi",
        "ratename": "Not Rated",
        "education": [{
        "course": "Chinese",
            "name": "Abubakar Tafawa Balewa University Bauchi",
            "awards": "BSc.",
            "gpa": "4.2"
    }, {
        "course": "English and International Studies",
            "name": "Achievers University Owo Ondo State",
            "awards": "MSc.",
            "gpa": "3.3"
    }]
}]

var initialData = JSON.parse(sampleData);
ko.applyBindings(new vm(initialData));
```

Comment: What issues have you run into?  Could you explain the problem in more detail?

Comment: Primarily one issue. Problem occurs when i'm filtering based on values in the nested array. e.g. education.course. Appears to work fine where the selected course corresponds to an object which has only one course within its education array. But when de/selecting a course that matches an object with multiple courses within its education array, the vm "breaks"/stops working and console logs "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'course' of undefined". Haven't been able to resolve that error.

Comment: Your fiddle is extremely complicated.  I would suggest taking it down a few notches (maybe apply three filters) and see if you can figure it out from there.  If not having only three will reduce the amount of code that others have to dig through to help you find the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Have updated the fiddle accordingly. I believe the error is probably somewhere within the logic for filtering the nested array. (line 22 of the fiddle) i.e.  if (self.selectedCourses().length > 0 || self.selectedSchools().length>0)...

Comment: Ok, I am taking a look at it now, much cleaner, but self.people() is referenced in line 12 but has no context yet - is that just from removing some code that was probably needed?

Comment: Actually self.people() refers to the observable array vm.people().